# Confidence in the compiler optimization when calculating a std::min very often

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, c++03

**The context:**

I allow my `DiagonalMatrix` class to be not square. Then, I can have a number of rows different to the number of columns. But, most of the time, only the size of the diagonal is called by the algorithms, and most of the time the matrix is square. Here is a subpart of my class:

```
class DiagonalMatrix:
{
  private:
    std::size_t nrows;
    std::size_t ncols;
  public:
    DiagonalMatrix(std::size_t num_rows, std::size_t num_cols) :
        nrows(num_rows), ncols(num_cols) {}
    std::size_t numRows() const
        { return this->nrows; }
    std::size_t numCols() const
        { return this->ncols; }
    std::size_t size() const
        { return std::min(this->nrows, this->ncols); }
};
```

**My question:**

How can I be confident in the optimization of the compiler to not systematically evaluate the `std::min` between `nrows` and `ncols` when I call `size()` ?

Or is it better to store the minimum value in the class, like this ?

```
class DiagonalMatrix:
{
  private:
    std::size_t nrows;
    std::size_t ncols;
    std::size_t nmin;
  public:
    DiagonalMatrix(std::size_t num_rows, std::size_t num_cols) :
        nrows(num_rows), ncols(num_cols), nmin(std::min(num_rows,num_cols)) {}
    std::size_t numRows() const
        { return this->nrows; }
    std::size_t numCols() const
        { return this->ncols; }
    std::size_t size() const
        { return this->nmin; }
};
```

**My configuration:**

Linux: GCC 4.4.7 & 4.8.5 (then, I don't use C++11)

Windows: Intel Composer XE 2013 SP1

Comment: Profile. For all we know, the additional field in DiagonalMatrix impacts CPU caches in a way that hurts performance more than evaluating a minimum of two numbers (a compare and a conditional move, usually).

Comment: BTW, GCC 4.8 is old and soon obsolete. Consider upgrading -on Linux- to at least GCC 6 (and better yet GCC 7, and in a few weeks GCC 8) in november 2017. Recent GCC optimize better and support C++11

Comment: It probably will be reevaluated each time, but that's a very cheap operation. This smells like a premature optimization.

Comment: Do your matrices resize on runtime?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: impossible, we must have compatibility of our libraries with clients using these version of GCC.

Comment: @ArashMohammadi: only with a `clear` or a `swap`. But it's enough to not put it as `const` (if this was what you suggest).